# WPF MvxEventToCommand not found

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvmcross

Few steps to test MvxEventToCommand in WPF:

1. Create new Wpf project (.net 4.6.1)
2. Install nuget package MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf
3. Add reference to System.Window.Interactivity
4. Add xaml code to MainWindow:

   ```
   xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
   xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Commands;assembly=MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf"
   ```

and

```
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <cmd:MvxEventToCommand Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

After this I get error:

> The name "MvxEventToCommand" does not exist in the namespace

Other namespaces from examples gives same result. What I doing wrong?
My temporary solving of problem is copying of MvxEventToCommand.cs source in my Wpf project...

**Update**:
Searching for "MvxEvenToCommand" or even "EventToCommand" in [repo](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross) returns no results. Does MvvmCross contains this class really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been removed from MvvmCross in 6.1. You can either copy it in yourself, or find another alternative.

The reason was that the dependency on `System.Window.Interactivity` was problematic when using multi-targeting. We would be happy to add it back in if we can get this solved. We would accept a PR for this.

Comment: Aren't assembly and namespace "MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Commands" suppose I use it in platform-specific UI - WPF?

Answer (score 0):

You will find this problem a million times on Stack Overflow and the rest of the internet. I struggle with it myself sometimes. Here are the steps I recommend to try to fix it.

**1. Clean and Rebuild the solution.**

Go to Build > Clean Solution then Build > Rebuild Solution. That might fix the problem.

**2. Check where your project is stored.**

Sometimes, when a solution is stored on a network drive, this problem will occur and will not go away. Try copying the solution to a local drive, and see if this resolves the problem

**3. Make sure your code is actually referencing the namespaces correctly.**

If you happen to be using MVVM, or even if not, make sure every file links where it is supposed to. Make sure your XAML has the right `x:Class` and make sure your data contexts are in order.

**4. Try running your IDE in administrator mode**

On rare occasions, this will fix things

**5. Do step 1 again**

**6. Cry**

Lie down, cry, and hope that some more experienced troubleshooter comes to help you, because I really have no idea what I am talking about. This is just what ultimately worked for me.

**7. Repeat Steps 1-6 until you abandon all hope of ever finishing your program**

That's about it. I hope this helps. And if you are not using Visual Studio, you will have to figure out how to rebuild the project yourself, though that shouldn't be hard.